# Does a security group rule overide NACL in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-security-group

I am trying to make a VPC with 3 servers, and enabling all traffic inside the VPC and to a specific IP address outside- a workstation.
I also want to block any other traffic.
I am having trouble understanding the logic of the security in the VPC:
If I block all traffic on the ACL level and allow only what I want on the security group level- will it work?
Basically, what I am trying to understand is how do I manage the outband traffic out of my subnet?

Comment: I was thinking maybe to make a rule in the NACL to deny allow inbound traffic from my specific IP address and deny everything else. will it work?

Comment: Good resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html#VPC_Security_Comparison

Answer (score 1):

The 2 services work together they do not act as an OR condition.

**Security Groups**

Security groups are evaluated on a host level, by default all traffic is blocked unless explicitly allowed any interactions that pass through an ENI will be evaluated against the security group.

**NACL**

A NACL on the other hand is evaluated at the subnet level. Traffic is evaluated as it enters (or leaves) a subnet. In fact if 2 instances sit in the same subnet and communicate privately then the NACL is never evaluated.

Rules for NACLs are evaluated in order from lowest to highest number and support both DENY and ALLOW.

If you block all traffic at the NACL level then the only communications that will be supported is between instances on the same subnet that have an inbound/outbound rule that matches in the security group.

Comment: So how do I block all the other traffic except the ones listed above? 
maybe- 
inbound rule 1- allow traffic from a specific IP.
inbound rule 2- deny all traffic.
outband rules- this is the point where it is not clear to me.

Comment: If this is the case I would suggest keep your default NACL inbound as is, for the security groups of instances allow inbound source of a security group attached to these instances or the IP ranges of the subnets/VPC. Then allow inbound access specifically the external IPs you want. If you want outbound traffic stopped from your instances you would need to list the IP ranges you wanted to allow and then have a higher rule to DENY :)

Comment: Cool. Seems reasonable. So deny ALL traffic outband after a rule to allow outband to a specific IP.

Comment: Exactly, sort your security groups first and then do the NACLs :)

Comment: Thanks! will give a try

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)